# How to load a class from annotations processor in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, classpath, classloader

I implemented an Annotation Processor and I'm trying to load a class that is referenced by some nested element of the current file being processed, for example the return type of a method.

When I run this code from command line with javac and passing the current project classpath it successfully runs, but when using eclipse I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException. See the example below:

```
public class MyAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

    for (TypeElement element : annotations) {
        try {
            TypeElement type = getMethodReturnType(element);
            Class<?> class1 = Class.forName(type.getQualifiedName().toString());
            // ..
            // do some processing with class1
            // ...

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I found that in eclipse the processor doesn't have the classpath of the current project. I could create an URLClassLoader to load those required classes but can't find a way to get the current project path.

Is there a way to get the project path from the annotation processor?

Comment: Well, the classpath and sourcepath settings are automatically passed to annotation processors based on project settings, so the problem could be with your project setup itself. Are you certain you have enabled annotation processing for your project?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure annotation processing is enabled, it works fine for files where no class needs to be loaded. Eclipse mentions what you say, but doesn't seem to do that:   
> Note: options such as "-classpath" and "-sourcepath" are automatically passed to all processors, with values corresponding to the project's Java settings.
When I get the classpath from the processor, using the System properties it only returns the jar from eclipse, and from the class loader of the processor I'm only getting the eclipse path. I'm working with eclipse Mars @SasikanthBharadwaj

Answer (score 2):

I give up on this one, it seems that you shouldn't be loading referenced classes from the annotation processor. Instead you should use typeUtils and elementUtils from the Processing Environment for anything you need.

It seems that you can do anything but invoke code in the referenced class, for example, to verify a given type implements some interface:

```
TypeMirror interfaceType = processingEnv.getElementUtils().getTypeElement("my.interfaceType").asType();
if(processingEnv.getTypeUtils().isAssignable(type, interfaceType)){
// do something
}
```